# nextjs v12 swcMinify set to true

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

decided to get rid of my babelrc as the new [rust compiler](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12#faster-builds-and-fast-refresh-with-rust-compiler) is being promoted and encouraged by vercel. however doing so immediately breaks my build. this is the only thing in my `babelrc.`

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true, "displayName": true }]]
}
```

and this is the error after i add

```
module.exports = {

  swcMinify: true
```

to my next.config.js and i run `next build`

[image]

not sure what i'm missing here since development build works fine, just the build that seems to be breaking on compile. any help would be appreciated

Edit: as requested, this is the entire error

```
static/chunks/pages/_app-434406ef89d5b351.js from Terser
error: 'eval' and 'arguments' cannot be used as a binding identifier in strict mode
     
      |
97440 |     function eval(str) {
      |              ^^^^

Caused by:
    0: failed to parse input file
    1: error was recoverable, but proceeding would result in wrong codegen
    2: Syntax Error
Error: error: 'eval' and 'arguments' cannot be used as a binding identifier in strict mode
     
      |
97440 |     function eval(str) {
      |              ^^^^

Caused by:
    0: failed to parse input file
    1: error was recoverable, but proceeding would result in wrong codegen
    2: Syntax Error
```

Comment: Can you include the entire error?

Comment: @code sure this. question updated

Comment: This seems to be a problem with Terser... you can manually use a Terser Webpack plugin. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57360588/how-to-use-terser-with-webpack.

Comment: There is actually a vercel thread on this and you should probably follow the codes there. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/30237 . Remember to `rimraf .next` before running build

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial thanks! taking a look at both threads now

Comment: @code thanks, mate! adding the terser plugin, seems to do the trick

Comment: Glad to hear that. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file and name it .babelrc (if it does not exist) and add following content:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"]
}
```

Also open next.config.js and add `swcMinify:false`

Comment: The SWC compiler minification process mangles the class and function names with a high probability of collision.